# If I cast an array of T to an array of Q (being Q derived from T) does it cast each element in turn?

Tags: java

I have the next snippet of code:

```
Certificate[] a = myFavouriteKeystore.getCertificateChain();
```

but I need to pass it to a method with the following signature:

```
void setCertificateChain(X509Certificate[] chain);
```

Can I do the following?:

```
setCertificateChain((X509certificate[]) a);
```

**IDE(eclipse) accepts it** and I assume that compiler does also, but my guess is that I'll get a `ClassCastException` even in the case that all the array elements are of class `X509Certificate` or a subclass of it.

Comment: The title of this question and the body do not match. No, each element is not cast in turn. The whole array reference is cast with one checked cast. They are the one example of "reified generics" (because they predate generics) in Java; the compile-time element type of an array is made part of the array's runtime type at instantiation. An array cast is based purely off the runtime type of the array, not the runtime type of the actual runtime elements. A better title may be "When do I get a `ClassCastException` while casting arrays?".

Comment: I wanted to ask if there were some "magic" that allowed to cast an array and so, the whole set of elements in the array would be casted to the new type.... but I've already seen that's not true.  Thank you for the clarification.  The title you suggest can be good in another scenario, but not in my case, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get `ClassCastException` *at runtime*, yes.

The cast is like lying to the compiler, saying that you *really* know what you are doing and even if the compiler can't prove that the cast will work - you are instructing it to trust you.

The compiler listens to you (not in all cases, i.e. you can't tell it to cast a String to an Integer for example, since `String` is final and can't have sub-classes), but at the same time will inject into the byte code  `checkcast` instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tested, and you are right.  Even in the case you have all the elements of compatible type, you need to copy to a new array of the casted to type.

Answer (score 3):

Tested, and it fails with a `ClassCastException` error:

```
package test;

public class TestClass {

    public static class A { }
    public static class B extends A { }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        A[] a = new A[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = new B();
        }
        B[] b = (B[]) a;  /* Error: ClassCastException, even if all elements are of type B */
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Eugene that so quick answered the question.

## NOTE

This agrees with the policy of casting generic containers.  For a container derived of a super class only the cast applies if the parameter types match.  E.g: `Set<A>` can be casted to `SortedSet<B>` only if `A` and `B` are the same type.

Comment: The elements don't matter, A[] is not a B[].

Comment: @Eugene, nope, but `SortedSet<A>` _is_ a `Set<A>` (in this case you can do the cast from `Set<A>` to `SortedSet<A>` ---provided the instance is indeed a `SortedSet<A>` referenced by a variable `Set<A>`---, but never if the type parameters are different)  The behaviour is as if `A[]` would be some kind of `Array<A>` and `B[]` some kind of `Array<B>`.  Even in case `B` derives from `A` the cast is not permitted, only if the arrays are of the same contained type.

Comment: @LuisColorado well yes a `SortedSet` is a `Set`, but not in reverse, a `Set` can be a `HashSet`; you say *Set<A> can be casted to SortedSet<B> only if ...*, `A` and `B` can be of the same type, but the `Set<A>` can actually be a `HashSet<A>` and the case would fail

Comment: Here is an example of a Set<Integer> getting cast to a HashSet<Number>, you have to use an intermediate because the compiler catches the Set<? extends Number>, but all the casts are valid. https://ideone.com/NM2pYI  Your array example is completely different B[] comes from Object, not from A[]. The array hierarchy is not exactly straightforward.

Comment: @matt well that double cast it a big liar though. you can even do `HashSet<String> numbers = (HashSet<String>) (HashSet) ints;` and if you de-compile, there are zero `checkcast` instructions

Comment: @Eugene exactly why you get a unsafe operation warning. Plus, when you get the "String" you'll get a class cast exception.

Comment: @matt _it _depends_. if you have `HashSet<String> numbers = (HashSet<String>) (HashSet) ints; System.out.println(numbers);` - it will not; if you do `System.out.println(numbers.iterator().next());` - it will.